# vs2022 using clang with windows link.exe to support auto link vcpkg

Tags: linker-errors, visual-studio-2022, clang++, vcpkg

in vs2022 i don't understand where i can change the linker from lld-link to the standard linker.exe when using vcpkg, i tried -link-ld=link and stuff but this all results in lldlink giving me an error because it does not support auto link (also specified in vcpkg documentation) -> it didn't change the linker

i also tried to use /linkToolExe=link.exe which changed the error message to clang-cl: no files
so thats something but idk how to continue from there.

Thx for any help :)

Recreating the scenario:

1. get vs2022 with clang tools from individual components
2. get vcpkg
3. get integrate vcpkg via cmd
4. new console c++ project
5. change Project->Properties->General->PlatformToolset to clang
6. set auto link to yes at Project->Properties->vcpkg

also i found this github page: https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/issues/4359 and at the bottom there is some solution but idk where to put his command stuff

apparently you can pass /Lib before everything to make it work with lld-link but idk how to put /lib before every command

please dont suggest cmake i know there are options there but i am not ready to learn this whole new thing now.
please also dont suggest to turn off auto link i know i can do that i just dont want to because that defeats the whole purpose of vcpkg

Comment: It is link.exe, not linker.exe

Comment: tested, still doesn't work